# Creating Dynamic String and Array references in for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dynamic

I need to create dynamic references to both strings and string Arrays within a for loop.
Is the following correct? In particular where I am trying to create a dynamic string reference string **sRef = "svert"+num;** and later a dynamic Array reference **string arrayRef = "s_array"+num;**

Any feedback welcome.

```
Vector3[] meshVerts = foo;
for(int num=0; num < meshVerts.Length;num++){

            string sRef = "svert"+num;
            sRef =meshVerts[num].ToString( format: "F4");
             sRef= sRef.Substring(1, 3);

            string arrayRef = "s_array"+num;
            string[] arrayRef = sRef.Split(',');
        }
'''
```

Comment: `Is the following correct?` Does it work? What is `s_array`?

Comment: The short answer (if I understand your intent) - you likely can't solve it the way you are trying to. Please share a [mcve] showing inputs and the outputs you are expecting (as _simple as possible_).

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a sample and test code for your question. I hope you find it interesting.

```
//fill vector3 array
Vector3[] meshVerts = new Vector3[3];
for (int i = 0; i < meshVerts.Length; i++)
{
    meshVerts[i] = new Vector3(i, i + 1, i + 2);
}

//fill string array
string[] arrayRef = new string[meshVerts.Length];
for (int num = 0; num < meshVerts.Length; num++)
{
    arrayRef[num] = string.Format("s_array{0}: {1}", num, meshVerts[num]);
}



//show vector3 array and string array
for (int i = 0; i < meshVerts.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Vector3 Array Row{0}:   X={1} ,Y={2} ,Z={3}", i, meshVerts[i].X, meshVerts[i].Y, meshVerts[i].Z));


    string[] newArray = arrayRef[i].Split(',');
    string firstCell = newArray[0].Split(':')[1].Replace("<", "");

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Row{1}:   X={2} ,Y={3} ,Z={4}", newArray[0].Split(':')[0], i, firstCell, newArray[1], newArray[2].Replace(">", "")));
}
```